# R How to delete a column if column values equal to the column name

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a data set that contains a bunch of columns where the column values(all values of that column) is exactly the same as that column name. How can I delete that column. I cannot delete the columns one by one as there are over 700 variables.
Thanks!

Comment: `data[colSums(sweep(data,2,colnames(data),"!="))>0]`

Comment: Thanks!.It reports "Error: NA column indexes not supported"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of how you could do it:

```
data = data.frame(x1 = rep(1,10), x2 = seq(1,20,by = 2),
                  x3 = rep("x3",10), x4 = 1:10, x5 = rep("x5",10))

col_rm = which(sapply(1:ncol(data), function(x) all(data[,x] == colnames(data)[x])))
data = data[,-col_rm]
```

basically what the code does it that finds if all the values of the column `x` are equal to the name of the column and finds all the columns that fulfill that condition and then i just remove them with `-`.

Comment: Hello Alejandro. I have another related question. What if the Column name is "Machine 01 Step 01 Power Supply B" and all column values equal to "Power Supply B". I want to search weather the column value is something contained in the Column name and delete that column too. Thanks!

Comment: you should use `grepl` something like this `grepl("Power Supply B","Machine 01 Step 01 Power Supply B")` where the first characters is the one you want to look for in the string, so it would be like  `grepl(columnValue,ColNames)` and if true is that the columnValue is in the column name

Comment: So I tried: col_rm <- which(sapply(1:ncol(test), function(x) grepl(x,colnames(test),ignore.case=TRUE))). It gives me more than [1:1236] numbers. It's more than my column numbers. Thanks!

Comment: it should be  which(sapply(1:ncol(test), function(x) grepl(test[,x],colnames(test),ignore.case=TRUE)))

Comment: So I tried your code, it returns "Error in which(sapply(1:ncol(test), function(x) grepl(test[, x], colnames(test),  : 
  argument to 'which' is not logical" Any clue? Thanks a lot !

Comment: this works for me but you might need to tweek it so it works ``which(sapply(1:ncol(data), function(x) any(grepl(data[1,x],colnames(data)[x],ignore.case=TRUE))))``

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```
data = data.frame(name1=rep("name1",5), name2=rep("name2",5), name3=rep("name3",5), name4=rep("name4",5)) #Some test data

ColsToRemove <- names(data)[which(sapply(data[1,], function(x){x %in% names(data)}))] #Finds where the column name is the same as the first entry and marks it for deletion

cleanData = data[ , !(names(data) %in% ColsToRemove)] #This deletes the columns named

head(data)
head(cleanData)
```

Comment: With your approach you would have to know which columns to you want to remove in advances

Comment: Updated to automatically find, based on the first entry - is that what you were after?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sweep` to determine all the values that are not equal to the colnames

```
data[colSums(sweep(data,2,colnames(data),"!="))>0]
```